# How remove items from ArrayCollection in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

This is my ArrayCollection I want to remove "Label:"Taxes", Value:2000" line from this arrayCollection. Guys how can do that without using forloops or using forloop?

```
public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Label:"Taxes", Value:2000},
            {Label:"Rent", Value:1000},
            {Label:"Bills", Value:100},
            {Label:"Car", Value:450},
            {Label:"Gas", Value:100},
            {Label:"Food", Value:200}
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {Label:"Taxes", Value:2000},
            {Label:"Rent", Value:1000},
            {Label:"Bills", Value:100},
            {Label:"Car", Value:450},
            {Label:"Gas", Value:100},
            {Label:"Food", Value:200}
        ]);


            var tempArr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(); // temporary ArrayCollection

            tempArr = ObjectUtil.copy(expenses) as ArrayCollection; //copy expences ArrayCollecttion to temp arrray before delete items

            for(var i:int=0;i<expenses.length;i++)
            {
                if(expenses[i].Label.toString()==label)
                {
                    tempArr.removeItemAt(i);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

For doing that you need to know item index. 
So `expenses.removeItemAt(0)` will work for you. 
If you have object but don't know index you can get it with `expenses.getItemIndex(myObject)` and then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

//Removing object using "remove" method as following:

```
trace("Remove First Item: "+ expenses.removeItemAt(0));
```

//Removing object using loop as following:

```
var indetToDelete:Object = expenses[expenses.length - expenses.length];

for(var item:int=0; item<expenses.length ; item++){
                trace("Label:"+expenses[item].Label+"Value:"+expenses[item].Value);

if((expenses[item].Label == indetToDelete.Label) && (expenses[item].Value ==  indetToDelete.Value)){

expenses.removeItemAt(item);
}

}
```

Hope this may help you.